# How to add favicon to php pages?

Tags: php, favicon

I have this line included in all of my pages.

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

As far as I know, all i need to do is place a file called favicon.ico in my root directory. I did that as well

[image]

But the favicon is not appearing. How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to put it in your web root, which is not necessarily the same as your root. I am not familiar with Plesk's directory structure, but it seems likely that your web root is the "httpdocs" folder, not the "Root directory".

Comment: as Joel said, put the favicon in the `httpdocs` folder.

Comment: I have moved the file into httpdocs folder. Yet the favicon is not appearing. U can view it live at gniconnection.com

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, your favicon.ico most probably is not located in your web root. You should try moving it into *httpdocs*. I doubt that your web server can access the file right now, besides that you would have to reference it as `"../favicon.ico"` from a document within *httpdocs*.

Comment: I have moved the file into httpdocs folder. Yet the favicon is not appearing. U can view it live at gniconnection.com

Comment: I do see the favicon now, I guess you need to clear the cache

Comment: Is it? i'm very sorry. I  will check it throughly.

Comment: Thank you for the screenshot :)